# É uma má prática fazer paginação direto no front-end?

Tags: angularjs, paginação

Tenho alguns sistemas `Java` + `AngularJS`, em alguns faço paginação no `back-end`, utilizando paginação do `Hibernate`,
ex:

```
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(10);
```

Porém recentemente encontrei algumas bibliotecas do `AngularJS` que fazem paginação, não notei diferença de performance pois não tenho muitos dados para testar. Essa é a [biblioteca](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) que estou utilizando.

- Fazer paginação direto no front-end com essas bibliotecas é uma má
  prática? Por que?
- Essas paginações podem atrapalhar no desempenho do meu sistema?
- Se elas atrapalham, quando devo usa-las?

Comment: Se for muita informação, e o usuário normalmente usar só as 1as páginas, você estará transportando sempre muito mais informação do que precisa. Se for pouca informação, e/ou normalmente o usuário precisar da paginação quase toda, talvez compense a economia de requisições. Como sempre, a resposta mágica é: **depende!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o você deva levar em consideração ao elaborar uma página seria:

- Quantidade de informação ser exibida;
- Necessidade do usuário de consumir toda essa informação;
- Agilidade em obter novos resultados com a mesma agilidade em que teria ao apenas exibir novos dados;

O `AngularJS` é muito bom nesse quesito, pois você pode controlar a quantidade de resultados exibidos em um `ng-repeat` através do filtro `limitTo`. É mais do que provado que o `ng-repeat` tem um grande impacto em performance quando má utilizado e/ou com grandes quantidades de dados. Então, nesse caso, a má pratica está mais associada ao modo como se usa o `ng-repeat` do que à paginação em `front-end` propriamente dita.

Acho que você deve levar em consideração, especialmente, a necessidade do usuário de consumir essa informação. Uma paginação de portfólio, notícias, por exemplo, é diferente da paginação de uma pesquisa. No portfólio é mais comum que o usuário navegue pelos resultados, enquanto que em uma lista de resultados de pesquisa, caso não seja encontrado nas primeiras exibições, é mais provável que seja feita uma nova pesquisa ao invés de uma navegação. Como é o caso da 2ª página do Google.

Então, tente responder o seguinte:

- Quão longa é sua lista de dados a ponto de criar um gargalo de performance?
- Quantas abas o usuário vai navegar?
- Qual a velocidade entre "acrescentar +1 página" vs "efetuar mais um request"?

Alterando apenas a quantidade limite do filtro `limitTo` você tem a exibição de mais dados bem dizer instantaneamente.

Acho difícil ter algum caso em que seja mais fácil fazer o `request` por etapas, do que fazer o `request` inteiro logo no início. Até por que hoje em dia, dificilmente alguém vai navegar por uma lista tão longa que seja improvável fazer todo o carregamento dela de uma única vez. Haja paciência...

Answer (score 3):

> Fazer paginação direto no front-end com essas bibliotecas é uma má
>   prática? Por que?

De maneira alguma é uma má prática. Tudo depende da quantidade de dado a ser recuperada do servidor. Esse deve ser o seu guia na hora de avaliar paginação *client* ou *server* *side*.

Não acredite quando te falarem que server side é sempre a melhor opção, pois se a quantidade a ser recuperada do servidor não for grande, então pra que complicar a sua vida tendo que implementar paginação no Hibernate se você pode delegar isso pra uma biblioteca como essa citada ou várias outras? A biblioteca jqGrid, por exemplo, trabalha muito bem com as duas opções.

Se o sistema for constituído de várias tabelas de cadastro, então para as que devem exibir poucos dados (ex: < 100 registros), utilize a paginação no lado do cliente. Você estará bem servido e evitará código do lado do servidor.

Além disso, a paginação no lado do cliente evita requisições, pois uma paginação *server side* requer pelo menos uma requisição a cada página solicitada.

> Essas paginações podem atrapalhar no desempenho do meu sistema?

Podem atrapalhar se você delegar a paginação de muitos dados para o cliente. Note que para paginar no lado do cliente é necessário que você tenha todos os dados carregados na memória do cliente, portanto, você precisa recuperá-los no servidor. Dependendo da quantidade de dados, isso pode demorar e fazer o sistema ficar lento para o usuário.